# What JavaScript and or Html should engine I should use?

Tags: javascript, html5

I took some classes on JavaScript and I know some html5. I took these classes so I can Learn Game Development!! I want to use JavaScript and not C# or C++ because I want easy cross platform with the browser. So do you guys know any good Java Game Engines? To be more specific: I really just want a Engine that has a good community so I can ask many questions. I like to learn a Engine step by step like asking the engines community how to do user controls or moving backgrounds. I hope someone get what I mean but any JavaScript engine you could name would be Great!! Thank you for Responding or reading! Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [BabylonJS](http://www.babylonjs.com) a lot. If you want to go into 3D Games, it is as of right now the best engine you can get and it's free.
In the [HTML5 Game Devs Forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com) the whole community is gathered. They are super nice and helpful. The creators and the main contributers are helping people with questions realy fast!

For 2D games Phaser might be for you. There is also a great community on the HTML5 Game Devs Forum for Phaser. But to be honest I havent really much experience with it.

Comment: I'm still pretty new too game development so I think it will be best if I start with a focused 2d engine. But I'll look into BabylonJS. Do you know of any ones that are 2d focused. And it's weird because I found the forums a little after I post this comment so I'll be on there for help. Thanks for responding!

Comment: As I stated above, for 2D my first look would be into Phaser.

Comment: GameMaker: Studios has html porting, its great for getting into 2D games. While it won't be written directly in JavaScript it will be cross platform and if anything it will probably be better that a JavaScript game.

Comment: Or coco2d-x-JS is a javascript game engine

Comment: I'll try out Phaser because it looks user friendly. Thank you for responding!